# One Liner to Build Multiple Screens

Tags: bash, sed

I have a script that processes a configuration file to launch a rendering job. I like to run these in screens.

The problem is, I can't name the screens, which leads to them being confusing if I need to see the status.

This works, running `assets/job1_config.py`, `assets/job2_config.py`, etc.

```
find assets -name 'job?_config.py' -exec screen -dm python3 procJobs.py {} \;
```

I tried to do this, but it doesn't work, as it seems to return the directory name, leading to an error message: "Cannot identify account 'assets'.

```
find assets -name 'job?_config.py' -exec screen -dmS `sed 's/.*\(job[[:digit:]]\).*/\1/' <<< '{}'` \;
```

The sed works properly when directly passed a string.

```
sed 's/.*\(job[[:digit:]]\).*/\1/' <<< 'assets/job1_config.py'
```

Is there any way to get this fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use backticks this way, as this command will be executed instantly before even starting `find` program. If you don't want to write any "helper" script you can try embedding whole command in additional shell:

```
find assets -name 'job?_config.py' -exec sh -c "screen -dmS `sed 's/.*\(job[[:digit:]]\).*/\1/' <<< '{}'`" \;
```

Comment: Never embed `{}` into a string passed to `sh -c`. It isn't safe. Instead use `sh -c 'command' - {}` and then use `$1` in the script to refer to the argument. This also lets you use parameter expansion, etc. on the value instead of needing external tools (if that works).

Comment: By "unsafe" you mean that if there was a bad directory name (rm -rf /) it'd just fire and destroy things, right? Or are there other issues running it that way?

In general the directory structure is fairly consistent, but I feel it's important to take all the precautions I can!